# How to change default Apache conf file for prestashop?

Tags: apache2, prestashop

How to make prestashop to use `prestashop.conf` file which is a clone of `000.default.conf` on my local server?

When I disable `000-default.conf`, prestashop don't load. 
When I enable that back, the web-page loads normally.

I've enabled `prestashop.conf` and reloaded/restarted Apache.

I use Apache2, prestashop 1.6.1, OS is Linux Mint.

Maybe someone can give me advice what else should I change. I haven't found solution so far.

P.S. prestashop.conf is complete clone of `000-default.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed the paths to match these of your website?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin youradminlogin@yourwebsite.com
     DocumentRoot "path/of/your/website"
     ServerName website-name.com
     Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
      <Directory "path/of/your/website">
         DirectoryIndex index.html
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require local
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make shure it is in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ !

After modifying this, you'll need to restart the server (sudo apachectl restart)

Comment: I've modified a little bit my prestashop.conf file, including in it some strings from your example. But still no success. File prestashop.conf is sites-available and sites-enabled. It is enabled and apache restarted.
When i write in address bar 'localhost/prestashop/' I receive message, that requested URL /prestashop/ was not found on this server

Comment: In `apache2.conf` there is `<Directory /home/user/web/>...`  
In `prestashop.conf`I wrote `DocumentRoot /home/user/web/prestashop` and `<Directory /home/user/web/prestashop...`

Comment: Have you added prestashop.local in /etc/hosts after "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: Yes i have. But still nothing. Leak of knowledges in Apache configuration makes problems for me.

Comment: have you tried putting "index.php" instead of "index.html"?